# Which guide should I follow for preparing Android in-app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I found two methods of implementation and they don't seem to be compatible with each other:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

For example, the first one tells you to unbind the billing service as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if (mService != null) {
    unbindService(mServiceConn);
}   
}
```

The training guide tells you to do this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
mHelper = null;
}
```

Which one is correct and should be followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest following http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html and start by including the example project (TrivialDrive) as they suggest in the aforementioned guide

Comment: I'm just worried that guide is outdated and is not compatible with API v3.

Comment: The project uses In-app Billing Version 3, mentioned throughout the guide

Comment: I see. So why is the implementation different from the first one? They contain a bunch of util functions with very complicated functions whereas the first one seems rather straightforward... I guess I'm just worried I might miss something.

Comment: It's the same. You can use either. If you look at the IabHelper you will see everything mentioned. Using the TrivialDrive you get the benefit of having these extra helper classes. Ofc there are some reduntant stuff in there but for getting started it is very useful. You can skip all these, use https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html and write everything from scratch based on your taste